# How to make vertical list 2 column using flexbox

Tags: html, css

I try to make 2 column list and vertical order using flexbox

```
<ul>
  <li>item 1</li>
  <li>item 2</li>
  <li>item 3</li>
  <li>item 4</li>
  <li>item 5</li>
  <li>item 6</li>
  <li>item 7</li>
  <li>item 8</li>
  <li>item 9</li>
  <li>item 10</li>
</ul>
```

see image for the example

[image]

Comment: put your css code

Comment: why not use column-count: 2?

Comment: @ChrisLi Heyy it's work many thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's a simple wrapping column layout in flexbox.

Each `li` element takes up `6em` height (`5em` height + `.5em` margin * 2), so we set the parent container to `30em` height to fit five elements.

```css
ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-content: flex-start;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 30em;
}

li {
  background: gray;
  width: 5em;
  height: 5em;
  margin: .5em;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>item 1</li>
  <li>item 2</li>
  <li>item 3</li>
  <li>item 4</li>
  <li>item 5</li>
  <li>item 6</li>
  <li>item 7</li>
  <li>item 8</li>
  <li>item 9</li>
  <li>item 10</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Yes!! this is what I am looking for, Thank you very much

Comment: Depends on height too much. What if it's flexible?

Answer (score -2):

**The HTML is straight-forward:**

```
<div class="items">
  <div class="item">Heriberto Nickel</div>
  <div class="item">Brittaney Haliburton</div>
  <div class="item">Maritza Winkler</div>
  <div class="item">Carmon Rigg</div>
  <div class="item">Alice Marmon</div>
  <div class="item">Lyman Steakley</div>
  <div class="item">Zenia Correa</div>
</div>

<div class="items">
  <div class="item">Heriberto Nickel</div>
  <div class="item">Brittaney Haliburton</div>
  <div class="item">Maritza Winkler</div>
  <div class="item">Carmon Rigg</div>
  <div class="item">Alice Marmon</div>
  <div class="item">Lyman Steakley</div>
  <div class="item">Zenia Correa</div>
</div>
```

**Using floats, the CSS for this would be:**

```
.items {
  overflow: hidden; /* simple clearfix */
}
.items .item {
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
}

.items {
  overflow: hidden; /* simple clearfix */
}
.items .item {
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
}
```

**This gives us four columns that wrap. We can also add a little bit of style to give it a more pleasing look:**

```
.items .item {
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: #e0ddd5;
  color: #171e42;
  padding: 10px;
}


.items .item {
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: #e0ddd5;
  color: #171e42;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

Comment: You copied and pasted this from here including the text, except you took an irrelevant example that has 4 columns and no flexbox. https://blog.kevinlamping.com/responsive-multi-column-lists-with-flexbox/